# $(A\cap B)C=AC\cap BC$ in an infinite group

Tags: group-theory

Is there an infinite group $G$ such that for every $A,B,C\subseteq G$,

$$1\in A\cap B\cap C~~\to ~~(A\cap B)C=AC\cap BC$$

Comment: $A, B, C$ are subsets, not necessarily subgroups, right?
And the product of subsets is the subset of all products of elements from each subset, right?

Comment: yes‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: Could you supply some context please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group with the described property.

Assume there is an element $g\in G$ of order $\ge 3$.
Then we can let $A=\{1,g\}$, $B=\{1,g^2\}$, $C=\{1,g\}$. Then $$g^2\notin (A\cap B)C=\{1\}C=\{1,g\}$$ whereas $$g^2\in AC\cap BC=\{1,g,g^2\}\cap \{ 1,g,g^2,g^3\}.$$ Hence any group with the desired property has only elements of order $\le 2$, i.e. $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g\in G$.

Assume $1,a,b$ are three distinct elements of $G$. Let $c=ab$. Then $c\ne 1$ because $a\ne b^{-1}=b$, $c\ne a$ because $b\ne 1$, and $c\ne b$ because $a\ne 1$.
With $A=\{1,a\}$, $B=\{1,b\}$, $C=\{1,c\}$, we have $$b\notin (A\cap B)C=C=\{1,c\},$$  whereas $$b\in AC\cap BC = \{1,c,a,ac=b\}\cap\{1,c,b,bc\}.$$

We conclude that $G$ has at most two elements.